# Gitlab Pull a branch to the local machine

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to copy a branch of the online repository (Gitlab) to my local machine. Let's assume the branch is called "Version1" - then I want to copy this branch to a new branch called "Version2" on my local machine. Because I dont want to overwrite this branch later. The problem i got is the following: Every time I create a new branch on my local machine it is a copy of the branch that I was before.

```
git pull origin Version1
```

does not work as i want.

Would be great if someone could help.

Comment: what about git fetch origin Version1

Answer (score 3):

You can create a local branch on your machine that is based off of the `Version` branch.

Use the [`checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) command with `-b`.

First switch to the branch you want to "copy":

```
git checkout Version1
```

Next, create your own branch that is based off of `Version1`:

```
git checkout -b Version2
```

Now, when you create commits while on the `Version2` branch, your local copy of `Version1` will remain unchanged.

[Here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) is a good article to learn more about branching.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to gitlab-git - so I still have a question :) - git checkout Version1 (which is at gitlab, but not on my local machine), does not work. I tried the following: "git branch Version2", "git checkout Version", "git pull origin Version1"--> it works so far. But I still got problems. What i want is the following: I want to create a local branch that is a identical copy of the "Versoin1" of the online repository. When i create for instance local "Version2" then there are files from the master branch and they stay at that branch after "git pull origin Version1"

Comment: @lars111 I see. So you already cloned right? And you don't have Version1? Try: `git fetch` which should fetch all remote branches for your origin. Then do `git branch --all` and see if "Version1" appears. If it does, and you have already created your "Version2" branch, then: `git checkout Version2; git reset --hard Version1`